# "Doubt and hopelessness fills my heart" or "fill my heart"

Tags: meaning, grammar, verbs

Which is grammatically correct?
"Doubt and hopelessness **fills** my heart"
Or
"doubt and hopelessness **fill** my heart"?

Comment: Doubt and hopelessness are two things, are they not? _A feeling_ of doubt and hopelessness is one thing.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey has a very good point. Beyond that, for a native speaker _fills_ sounds  _off_.

Answer (score 0):

I must say that I often come across this problem in writing and there are occasions when I do choose the singular (more rarely than the plural though) in order to show that ***the two subjects refer to two different aspects of the same thing***. Let me explain myself. In this sentence:

> My ***faith and hope is*** that she shall survive this ordeal and stand tall to claim her rights.

I am saying that ***faith*** and ***hope*** are two ways of describing my ***one aspiration***.

On the other hand, if I say:

> My ***faith and (my) hope are*** that she shall survive this ordeal and stand tall to claim her rights.

I am considering ***my faith*** and ***my hope*** as two different feelings, of *belief in the fact that something will happen* and of *optimistically desiring something to happen*.

So in certain ways, this is a matter of what you really mean. If ***doubt*** and ***hopelessness*** are two different things for you, put ***fill***. If they are the aspects of the same feeling, put ***fills***.